# Wget Command Not Working in Cygwin for Windows

Tags: cygwin, wget

I am now using Wget and I download Cygwin as a terminal. Also, I use http://djangoproject.com/download/1.3.1/tarball/ as a test link to download files.

The install process runs smoothly, but when I try to download the file from the above link, an error occurs as I can not find the file on my computer, I can only find a file named `"index.html"`. But the file shoud be a `.rar` file. Here is the screenshot of the problem. Thank you for your help.

The main code is `wget http://djangoproject.com/download/1.3.1/tarball/`

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot (you can copy & paste code into this site, use the "Code Sample" toolbar button) says "301 Moved Permanently" a few times, but then downloads the file, but without using an output name option or `--trust-server-names` it gets saved to index.html - that's your downloaded file.

Use `--trust-server-names` to, well, use the filename the server tells you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am new to `wget` and your solution works well.

Comment: Welcome :) It can be pretty complicated, can download an entire site or be used in scripts. But for just downloading 1 or 2 files a web browser is usually easier

Comment: Thanks a lot. This example is only a test. Could you take a look at my new question at https://superuser.com/questions/1188349/how-to-download-multiple-files-using-wget-from-cygwin-for-windows ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem, these sites actually like upvotes (up-arrow link on the left side, near the check-mark) as a way of saying "thanks" & "that's useful", so feel free to upvote :-) They almost don't like just saying "thanks", it's kind of weird & almost impolite that way, but I guess it keeps the site more focused on questions & answers & useful info. FYI, I spotted something to change in the other question & posted an answer there.