# How to download multiple files using Wget from Cygwin for Windows

Tags: windows, cygwin, download, wget

I have a link which indludes 12 files and I want to download all of them using just one command in `Wget`. And I use Cygwin as a terminal to run`Wget`.

The link is https://hydro1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/NLDAS/NLDAS_FORA0125_M.002/1985/ and I only want all `.grb` files under this link. I have tired the following code, but it just downloads all `.xml` files.

I find some advices from https://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/recipes/?q=recipes/How-to-Download-Data-Files-from-HTTP-Service-with-wget ,but I still cannot solve the problem. Thanks for any help.

```
wget --load-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --save-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --keep-session-cookies -r -c -nH -nd -np -A nc4,xml "https://hydro1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/NLDAS/NLDAS_FORA0125_M.002/1985/"
```

Thanks to all the help, I have fixed it but then it comes to a more complicated question. It requires username and password, which should be the case, but I do not know how to `Create a .netrc file` and `Create a cookie file` as recommended by https://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/recipes/?q=recipes/How-to-Download-Data-Files-from-HTTP-Service-with-wget.

Here is a biref description of what I need to do.

```
To run wget, you need to set up .netrc and create a cookie file:
Create a .netrc file in your home directory.
a. cd ~ or cd $HOME
b. touch .netrc
c. echo "machine urs.earthdata.nasa.gov login <uid> password <password>" >> .netrc
     where <uid> is your user name and <password> is your URS password
d. chmod 0600 .netrc (so only you can access it)

Create a cookie file. This file will be used to persist sessions across calls to Wget or Curl. For example:
a. cd ~ or cd $HOME
b. touch .urs_cookies
```

I wonder how I can do this in `Wget` from Cygwin for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only looking at your example, it shows `-A nc4,xml` which would explain only downloading .xml files, there must not be any nc4 files at that link.

Anyway, here's what `man wget` says about `-A`:

```
Recursive Accept/Reject Options
   -A acclist --accept acclist
   -R rejlist --reject rejlist
       Specify comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or patterns
       to accept or reject. Note that if any of the wildcard
       characters, *, ?, [ or ], appear in an element of acclist or
       rejlist, it will be treated as a pattern, rather than a suffix.
       In this case, you have to enclose the pattern into quotes to
       prevent your shell from expanding it, like in -A "*.mp3" or -A
       '*.mp3'.
```

So for only grb files, try using `-A grb` as in:

```
wget --load-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --save-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --keep-session-cookies -r -c -nH -nd -np -A nc4,xml "https://hydro1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/NLDAS/NLDAS_FORA0125_M.002/1985/"
```

---

After Edits:

Username & Password should be fairly easy, try adding these:

```
   --user=user
   --password=password
       Specify the username user and password password for both FTP
       and HTTP file retrieval.  These parameters can be overridden
       using the --ftp-user and --ftp-password options for FTP
       connections and the --http-user and --http-password options for
       HTTP connections.
```

again from `man wget`. And read about the `--save-cookies file` and ``--read-cookies file` options in there, it may be tricky to get cookies saved from a web browser, if they don't work in wget.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It now requires username and password which should be the case. However, I am new to `wget` and I do no know how to `Create a .netrc file` and `Create a cookie file` as recommended by the first link I post in the question. Could you also take a look? I have edited the question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In the turorial under the link, it says "touch .netrc". What does this mean?

Comment: `touch` is a program, it changes the timestamp of a file (and creates a file if it doesn't exist). The tutorial link seems to have comments mixed in with commands, so it's not super clear what they want typed & what they're just talking about, but always look for & read a `man` page for new commands - sometimes there are `info` pages too that may be different. Be careful copying & pasting in commands you're unsure of, some can do strange or unwanted things (but NASA should be a safe enough site to not worry much)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I do not know why, but follow your advice, it finally works! One more question, you talk about reading a `man` page, what is the `man` page? Is it a tutorial or something else?

Comment: `man`  is "*an interface to the on-line reference manuals*", almost every terminal command has a man page that says what the command does & how to use it. I think Cygwin should have the man pages, and here's their FAQ for [Where's the documentation?](https://www.cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.resources.documentation)

Answer (score 1):

Easy. You're missing an option

```
wget --load-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --save-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --keep-session-cookies -r -c -nH -nd -np -R html,xml -A grb "https://hydro1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/NLDAS/NLDAS_FORA0125_M.002/1985/"
```

`-R` to reject all `html` and `xml` files, and `-A` to accept only `grb` files

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have edited the question. Could you also take a look?